# dbt throws schema does not exists where documentation says it should be created automatically

Tags: dbt

According to the DBT documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/create-a-schema :

> Nope! dbt will check if the schema exists when it runs. If the schema does not exist, dbt will create it for you.

However, when I tried to write to a nonexisting schema (the one in my profiles.yml) I received an error about the schema not existing.

Comment: What was the error you got? Can you share your model file?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Hanan Sometimes not a bad idea to isolate from dbt_project.yml (since it can get crowded, formatting etc.) and instead do a model [config block](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-configs#general-configurations) as a starting point. Something like `{{ config( database="<string>", schema="<string>" ) }}` and then running that model selectively with `dbt run --models my_model_name` will surface permissions issues or other errors resulting from dbt packages, dbt version to python version mismatch etc.